# GET method for a "locations" route in node js application is failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is day two for with node js and mongo. I've tried various tutorials and right now, I'm trying to follow this one: 
https://github.com/amejiarosario/todoAPIjs/commit/d3be6a287e8aff39ab862971da4f050d04e552a1

**Problem:**

I have an express application that launches, but doesn't return data from my database. I'm assuming that I'm either calling the method incorrectly, or somewhere I've substituted uppercase for lower? Or made something singular that should be plural? 
If you can help me pin point where my mistake is, I'd appreciate it.

**Code / Background Info**

For now, I've only rigged up a GET request in my API.
I launch the application like so:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/inventory$ DEBUG=inventory ./bin/www
model schema defined
successfully exported database schema
inside locations routing file
connection successful
curl localhost:3000/locations
curl localhost:3000/locations/            
curl localhost:3000/Locations/
curl localhost:3000/Locations
```

I've also tried starting the app by calling "node app.js" and then opening a browser and running "localhost:3000/locations".  I get a "localhost refused to connect" error message.  However, as you can see from the debug output when I run on via command line, I am connecting to the database... and also creating the schema.

**Application Structure:**

This is my folder structure for my express application:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/inventory$ ls -lah
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x  8 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:37 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:22 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 jlee jlee 1.8K Aug  2 14:37 app.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:02 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:40 models
drwxrwxr-x 75 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:04 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 jlee jlee 2.9K Aug  2 14:14 npm-debug.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 jlee jlee  384 Aug  2 14:02 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  5 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:02 public
drwxr-xr-x  2 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:42 routes
drwxr-xr-x  2 jlee jlee 4.0K Aug  2 14:02 views
```

The following sections will show you the key pieces of code:

**app.js**

```
  1 var express = require('express');
  2 var path = require('path');
  3 //var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
  4 var logger = require('morgan');
  5 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  6 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  7 
  8 var routes = require('./routes/index');
  9 var users = require('./routes/users');
 10 var locations = require('./routes/locations');
 11 
 12 var app = express();
 13 
 14 //mongoose connection info and basic connect test
 15 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 16 mongoose.connect('mongodb://10.66.6.111/inventory', function(err) {
 17     if(err) {
 18         console.log('connection error', err);
 19     } else {
 20         console.log('connection successful');
 21     }
 22 });
```

**routes/locations.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var loc = require('../models/Location.js');    
console.log('inside locations routing file');

/* GET /todos listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('Inside GET method');
   loc.find(function (err, locations) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(locations);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/Location.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sip_domain: String,
  brn: String,
  ndc: String,
  type: String,
  playbook_run_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  status: Boolean,
  tenant_name: String,
  customized: Boolean,
});

console.log('model schema defined');
module.exports = mongoose.model('location', LocationSchema);
console.log('successfully exported database schema');
```

**Database**

In the inventory database, I have a collection called "locations" (note it's plural, whereas in my model, I use singular)

I'm currently reading up on express routing here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html  but in the meantime, if you see where I've gone astray, I'm all ears!

Thanks

**EDIT 3**

added these lines to bottom of app.js: (right before the module.exports call)

```
 73 var http = require('http');
 74 var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
 75 http.createServer(app).listen(port);
 76 
 77 module.exports = app;
```

And when I try to test:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/inventory$ DEBUG=inventory ./bin/www
model schema defined
successfully exported database schema
inside locations routing file
connection successful
curl localhost:3030/locations
```

Comment: try replace with this line loc.find({},function (err, locations)

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo sorry, can you clarify what you mean?  i don't understand.  sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the server creation.

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

Alternatively, use:

```
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

These lines should be at the bottom of `app.js`, before `module.exports`.

Comment: hi there.  i've added that line but it hasn't changed anything.  i will post a link to pastebin with entire app.js

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pg23p6ib - please check out line 39.  That's what I added.  Maybe I need to tell it to explicitly listen on port 3000?

Comment: where do i add this?  I'm assuming app.js but any specific line there?  I tried adding it to the top of the app.js file and retested.  using localhost:3030 but the GET is still not triggered.

Comment: i put those lines right before module exports... and then tried again.  it's still a no go.  The debug line inside the GET method never gets displayed / called.  see edit 3

Comment: You still see the "connection refused" error? Or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118954/discussion-between-happydevdays-and-mparnisari).

Comment: ok my bad.  So after adding the port information, although the command line curl request is still failing... it is working via the browser.  SO I think I will mark this question as answered... and then post another one about diff btween command line and browser

Comment: Your curl request is missing the GET verb.